# Custom Privacy for minors

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to forbid / block posts from minors? If not so, how can it be achieved?

For example, something like in this below picture, (accented with a red arrow) Based on users age, some posts should not be shown.

[image: sample]

Comment: Is this a Facebook feature request? If so, you are most certainly in the wrong place. Please read our [help].

Comment: This is not Facebook suggestions box

Comment: Well, what about after the edition?

Comment: So you're looking for a way to post but exclude people who are underage? No, there's nothing like that out of the box. Besides, the definition of "minor" can vary by country. I think your current viable alternative is to put your friends who you know are minors into a list, and then use the usual "exclude from list" feature.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Facebook definition of minor, you should ideally be reporting underage (13) accounts. If you are looking for selective privacy, it would be best to just group all you friends who are under a certain age into a list.

Example, "My friends who were born in 1993"

https://www.facebook.com/search/1993/date/users-born/me/friends/intersect